# mysqldump - username takes "-p" as well

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I use the following script to read database credentials from a Wordpress installation:

```
DB_NAME=$(sed -n "s/define( *'DB_NAME', *'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" wp-config.php)
DB_USER=$(sed -n "s/define( *'DB_USER', *'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" wp-config.php)
DB_PASSWORD=$(sed -n "s/define( *'DB_PASSWORD', *'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" wp-config.php)
DB_HOST=$(sed -n "s/define( *'DB_HOST', *'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" wp-config.php)
```

When I echo the variables like this:

```
echo $DB_NAME;
echo $DB_USER;
echo $DB_PASSWORD;
echo $DB_HOST;
```

Everything is fine. When I use them in a `mysqldump` statement:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -u${DB_USERNAME} -p${DB_PASSWORD} ${DB_NAME} > ../backups/${SQL_BACKUP} 2>&1
```

or

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -u$DB_USERNAME -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME > ../backups/$SQL_BACKUP 2>&1
```

I get this error message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user '-8zSkcRrgVad3F'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

When I use the statement as this:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -udatabaseuser -p8zSkcRrgVad3F database > ../backups/test.sql 2>&1
```

Everything works fine. I have no special chars in my user/database/password, but the command takes the `-p8zSkcRrgVad3F` as the username as well?  Do I need to trim the values before or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the username is empty, so the actual command looks like

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -u -p8zSkcRrgVad3F ...
```

(*8zSkcRrgVad3F* being your password)

First, add the spaces between the flags and the variables, and second - I think the error is just you using wrong variable names. You mention testing `echo $DB_USER` which works, but you use `$DB_USERNAME` in the command.

Comment: Thanks. That's it :( I've been blind. One question though. What's the difference between $VAR and ${VAR} ?